# I am reading/I read this book (for) three hours every other day

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

1 Is it true that "for" means three hours in a row while without "for" it means three random hours?

2 Which tense fits better with this sentence? Or both are OK?

> 1 I am reading this book for three hours every other day.
>
> 2 I read this book for three hours every other day.
>
> 3 I am reading this book three hours every other day.
>
> 4 I read this book three hours every other day.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the difference is whether the hours are contiguous, I think it's more about whether the hours apply to each thing individually, or to all things when combined.

If you mean that you spend three hours every other day reading the book, I would use #2:

> I read this book for three hours every other day.

You might assume it's at one sitting, but it doesn't have to be.

If you say:

> I read this book three hours every other day.

It's not clear to me if you mean three hours each day or three hours in total across the "every other days."

The present continuous "am reading" might be valid, but it sounds awkward. It would be better if you added something to it, for example:

> I'm reading this book for three hours and I'm reading that one for four.

> So I'm reading this book for three hours every other day and then he tells me that it's the wrong book!